# CGAL union misunderstanding

Tags: c++, cgal

I am usion the `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union(),` function to compute the union of 2 meshes.

When I use the code exemple from the website (https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2corefinement_mesh_union_8cpp-example.html) and the provided off files **blobby.off** and **eight.off**, everything goes fine.

Unfortunately when I use other off files I am getting and error that I don't understand :

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : it_poly_hedge!=edge_to_hedge.end()
File       : /usr/local/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/Corefinement/Visitor.h
Line       : 1008
```

Here is the concerned code in Visitor.h :

```
    //WARNING: in few case this is needed if the marked edge is on the border
    //to optimize it might be better to only use sorted pair. TAG_SLXX1
    Node_id_pair opposite_pair(node_id_pair.second,node_id_pair.first);
    it_poly_hedge=edge_to_hedge.find(opposite_pair);
    CGAL_assertion( it_poly_hedge!=edge_to_hedge.end() );
```

You can find the files I use here : 
https://pool234.seedbox.fr/files/index.php/s/H87xL0Ema9HC44P
(pwd : share)

Thank you for you help.

Comment: `mesh2.off` is not a valid input mesh (self-intersections due to duplicated edges). If you first fix it by calling [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::stitch_borders()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga15f047f56af2fee3e491120db4dc69a3), you'll get your result.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks you so much.

Comment: These comments should be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the aswner from sloriot :

> mesh2.off is not a valid input mesh (self-intersections due to
>   duplicated edges). If you first fix it by calling
>   CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::stitch_borders(), you'll get your
>   result.

Thx